# How to hide headers of a AJAX Post request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

If somebody intercepts my Post request after selecting something, he gets the following details  in between :

```
oId=01&opCode=10&ocyCode=998
```

If here, when intercepted, he changes opCode from 10 to 29, the page that follows displays changed opCode 29 and my original selection which was 10 is lost. 
Is there any way I can encode these headers or any filter or some spring security that can handle these changes in the header?

Comment: What do you mean `intercept`?  Somewhere in between the way from the browser to the server, or already in the browser?

Comment: You can't hide this from the end user. That's why you need to validate parameters on the server, to make sure the user is allowed to access the data they request.